# Syntax Error in function definition

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, integration

I'm trying to define a function that will integrate a function that takes an array as an input. I understand that this may not be possible, and was wondering what can be done to reconcile this? Here is the relevant code:

```
def mp(SNR2, *events):
    events = np.asarray(events).reshape((Ntrig,Nsamp))
    bessel = special.iv(0,np.sqrt(x*SNR2(event)))
    exp = np.exp(-0.5*(x+SNR2(event)))
    I = integrate.quad(lambda x: exp*bessel,0,SNRth**2)[0]
    return np.asarray([np.array[I for event in events[i]] for i in range(len(events))]).reshape(events.shape)
```

`events` is a (37,100) array. SNR2 is a previously defined function, and SNRth is just a float.

Comment: Wow, that is a terrifyingly long line of code. That would make debugging pretty difficult. What is the full traceback of the error?

Comment: The nice thing about such a long line of code is that there's rarely any doubt about which line the error is in!

Comment: @user3776468 please put the traceback in the question if you can. That line is so long your comment is being covered up by an ad!

Comment: There's no traceback error, just a little arrow pointing to the long line and "Syntax error: invalid syntax"

Comment: This code is so bad, it even screws up the SO HTML layout!

Comment: @tobias_k hmmm.. but isn't that the correct way to run through the items in an array?

Comment: Alright guys, the code is ugly. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3776468 break it up in understandable pieces.

Comment: I think there are some `()` missing after `np.array`: Try `np.array([...])` instead of just `np.array[...]`

Comment: made the code look cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to (1) get an item from `np.array` (probably not...) or (2) call `np.array`?

(1)

```
def mp(SNR2, *events):
    ...
    return np.asarray([np.array[[I for event in events[i]]] for i in range(len(events))]).reshape(events.shape)
```

(2)

```
def mp(SNR2, *events):
    ...
    return np.asarray([np.array([I for event in events[i]]) for i in range(len(events))]).reshape(events.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some `()` missing after `np.array`:

```
np.array[integrate.quad(lambda: ...,0,SNRth**2)[0] for event in events[i]]
```

This way, that `[...]` expression (your list comprehension) is interpreted as an index or slice to a list, and in this context `... for event in ...` is invalid syntax.

You probably want to create an `np.array` from the list comprehension. Try this:

```
np.array([integrate.quad(lambda: ...,0,SNRth**2)[0] for event in events[i]])
```

This will get rid of the syntax error, but there might still be logical errors in this expression. While Python can be tempting to write all sorts of complex one-liners, do yourself a favor and split this up into several lines, so your compiler can give you more precise error messages and you can check intermediate results.